# Jenkins build inside a docker container with generated reports

Tags: jenkins, docker, pytest, python-coverage

I am new to Jenkins and Docker and even after some researches, I do not find the way to do these things.

I want to :

- Execute pytest and python-coverage on my project inside a docker container.
- This should generate test and coverage reports
- Access the generated reports and read them with some Jenkins'plugin.

When I try locally with Docker, it is working. I created a Dockerfile which creates a docker image with the libs needed and the source code inside it, then a script is called when the container is created and run the tests. I can see that it is working because I used cat and was able to see the generated reports inside my terminal.

My problem here is : How can I have access to the reports generated inside the container in Jenkins and read them with plugins after.

EDIT : So here an example of what I am trying to do so you can have a better idea.

First, my Dockerfile example :

```
# starting from debian image
FROM debian

# install pytest and coverage to execute my tests
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python-pytest \
    python-coverage

# add source files to the image
ADD . /HelloPython/

WORKDIR /HelloPython/

# execute shell script which run tests
CMD sh ./compil.sh
```

My compil.sh contains my tests execution

```
# Run unit tests and generate JUnit reports in the reports directory
py.test --junitxml reports/test-results.xml test*.py

# Generate reports of the test code coverage
python-coverage run -m unittest discover
python-coverage xml -o reports/test-coverage.xml
```

And here my jenkins log when I run it with the Cloudbees plugin :

```
Démarré par l'utilisateur chris
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HelloPythonCover
Build Docker image from ./Dockerfile ...
$ docker build --file /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HelloPythonCover/Dockerfile /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HelloPythonCover
Sending build context to Docker daemon 8.704 kB

Step 1 : FROM debian
 ---> 1b088884749b
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y   python-pytest   python-coverage
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a5883bbc27e4
Step 3 : ADD . /HelloPython/
 ---> c03ecb80040c
Removing intermediate container d2cc8ea14c11
Step 4 : WORKDIR /HelloPython/
 ---> Running in dc3b08c6fa02
 ---> 20f41970849c
Removing intermediate container dc3b08c6fa02
Step 5 : CMD sh ./compil.sh
 ---> Running in 14ceca0e5975
 ---> 853cb296b94f
Removing intermediate container 14ceca0e5975
Successfully built 853cb296b94f
Docker container faaedb777e032e38586278ad776e1561a9f1c5a92536c06bca7e3af12b74a355 started to host the build
$ docker exec --tty faaedb777e032e38586278ad776e1561a9f1c5a92536c06bca7e3af12b74a355 env
[HelloPythonCover] $ docker exec --tty --user 116:125 faaedb777e032e38586278ad776e1561a9f1c5a92536c06bca7e3af12b74a355 env BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#29 BUILD_ID=29 BUILD_NUMBER=29 BUILD_TAG=jenkins-HelloPythonCover-29 BUILD_URL=http://localhost:8080/job/HelloPythonCover/29/ CLASSPATH= EXECUTOR_NUMBER=0 HOME=/root HOSTNAME=faaedb777e03 HUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=bd683ee6091ff880 HUDSON_URL=http://localhost:8080/ JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=bd683ee6091ff880 JENKINS_URL=http://localhost:8080/ JOB_NAME=HelloPythonCover JOB_URL=http://localhost:8080/job/HelloPythonCover/ NODE_LABELS=master NODE_NAME=master PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin TERM=xterm WORKSPACE=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HelloPythonCover /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6836918802627685893.sh
Stopping Docker container after build completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

So my primary goal here is to find a way for jenkins to get access to the reports generated. Also, Is there a way to see what is going inside the docker container while building ? For example, I tried to put a `cat` inside my shell script to see the reports while I tried locally, but in Jenkins I can not find a way to see it.

Comment: which build mechanism you are using? could you checked the log location mentioned in your build file?

Comment: My explanation is wrong, I will edit it. In fact, I am just running pytest and python-coverage on my source code to generate reports about unit tests and code coverage.

Comment: I suggest shared volumes.

Comment: Do you use this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin)?

Comment: I use [this one](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Custom+Build+Environment+Plugin). I do not really know which would be better for my case.

Comment: What's your host OS? Did you read all the documentation on the plugin? Seems a common use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Either [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) or [Docker Slaves Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Slaves+Plugin) should work fine.

Just be sure that the generated report is in xUnit format that Jenkins can "understand" and add a Post-build Action to publish the tests result pointing to the right path where it is like this:

[image: Publish JUnit Test]

Jenkins will copy that generated report to outside the container.

If your coverage tool is generating HTML reports you can use the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) just like the publish step described above.

Comment: The generated reports are in JUnit format so it is okay. However, I tried with the docker plugin but at the beginning of the build, I try to execute my tests with "py.test --junitxml reports/test-results.xml test*.py" but it says that it can not find the file. I tried with and without my sources in the docker image, but it is not working for both.

Comment: There could be a problem in your tests or at least in the test reporter. To make sure your tests are generating a report, try running a Shell script listing the files inside that destination path you defined, do this as build step right before the post actions section for debugging.

Comment: My tests seem to work properly. When I execute it in local, or in jenkins without being in a container, everything is working great. I think the problem is that i have not access to what is inside the container. The "only" thing I need to do is having access to the files inside the container, and I did not find how to do it at this time.

Comment: @Whin3 did you manage to get this working inside a container?

Comment: @OlivierTo If I remember correctly, I managed to get this working some weeks later but I don't remember how, sorry

Comment: @whin3 Ok... no problem for me i managed this working using pipeline script 
` newApp.inside('-e NODE_ENV=test') {
            sh 'npm install --dev'
            sh 'gulp test:unit'
        }
        junit 'reports/*.xml'`
As docker container home repository is a shared volume with local jenkins workspace

Answer (score 2):

Docker copy (docker cp) can copy files from the container file system out.  See [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) for details.  You can use this command in Jenkins to retrieve the coverage and unit test results from your container after the build completes.