# Jenkins: How to use JUnit plugin when Maven builds occur within Docker container

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a Pipeline where Jenkins builds my Docker image, runs tests, and then deploys the container if the tests pass.  The problem is that I have maven running inside the docker container, and I can't actually access the published tests until I run the container. I want the Docker container to be ran and deployed after the tests pass.  This seems like a simple thing to do, but I can't think of a good way to do it.  Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:10 as step-one

COPY ./ /var/www/java/
WORKDIR /var/www/java

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y maven 

RUN mvn clean package -X

ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar",  "target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Building..'
                    sh 'docker build -t spring-image .'

                }
            }
            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Testing..'
                    junit '/var/www/java/target/surefire-reports/TEST-ma.SpringTest.xml'                 
                }
            }


            stage('Deploy') {
                steps {
                    echo 'Deploying....'
                        sh 'docker run -i -d --name spring-container spring-image'
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an temporary container just before `junit` to extract test results files to copy test result to your workspsace. And finally remove it

```
sh 'docker create --name temporary-container spring-image'
sh 'docker cp temporary-container:/var/www/java/target/surefire-reports .'
sh 'docker rm temporary-container'
junit 'surefire-reports'
```

You could also take a look do [docker-pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) documentations which provides you some abstraction to build docker images

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo Matheu.  This looks pretty good and makes a lot of sense.  I'm going to give this a try and look closer at the link you provided.

Comment: You know, sometimes I just want to toss the Pipeline tooling and do it from shell. I get it but if you open a Docker container you can just publish within the pipeline itself.

Comment: Please tell me this is not why I lost the last 4 hours...

Answer (score 3):

You can use fact that **docker container home repository is a shared volume with local jenkins workspace**.

Simplest pipeline script:

```
newApp.inside('-e NODE_ENV=test') { sh 'npm install --dev' sh 'gulp test:unit' } junit 'reports/*.xml'
```

A bit complex example with some collateral work in separate stages (note that maven build image is using .m2 cache as non-root user):

```
    try {
    buildEnvImg.inside("-v /jenkins/.m2:/var/maven/.m2 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2 -v /jenkins/.cache:/var/maven/.cache -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock") {
        stage('Compile') {
            sh 'mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven -B -DskipTests clean compile'
        }
        stage('Build jar') {
            sh 'mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven -B -DskipTests package'
        }
        stage('Build docker') {
            sh 'mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven -B -DskipTests jib:dockerBuild'
        }
        stage('Test') {
            echo 'Going to execute mvn test, thus automated tests contained in project will be compiled and executed.'
            sh 'mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven -B test'
        }
    }
} finally {
    junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
}
```

Solution digged out from [Jenkins build inside a docker container with generated reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476811/jenkins-build-inside-a-docker-container-with-generated-reports) .

Comment: Good example on how to use native Jenkins Pipeline tooling.